# no sensor_msgs/MagneticField Illuminance?

Tags: sensor-msgs, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI

i want to use a sensor_msgs/MagneticField and sensor_msgs/Illuminance type message
but my distribution (fuerte)  don't have those types.
(i checked the file sensor_msgs/msg)
so i get the error
ERROR: Cannot load message class for [sensor_msgs/Illuminance]. Are your messages built?

my messages are built, in fact i used from the same topic the sensor_msgs/imu

what should i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74101/no-sensor_msgs/magneticfield-illuminance?/) by [rem870](https://answers.ros.org/users/5383/rem870/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2013-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could make an overlay of the sensor_msgs package using the groovy one in your fuerte build.
Under the assumption that the older messages weren't changed, this should be OK, but everyone using this would need the same overlay.

The alternative is to define those messages yourself for your fuerte build (as a custom package)

Which is better depends on what you plan to do. If you want to connect to a groovy system, the first way would be better.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rem870](https://answers.ros.org/users/5383/rem870/) on 2013-08-21**:
what do you mean :define those messages yourself for your fuerte build.???
here:http://www.ros.org/wiki/sensor_msgs
in the fuerte there is illuminance and magnetic field. i have reinstalled sensor_msgs but its the same.

**Comment by [rem870](https://answers.ros.org/users/5383/rem870/) on 2013-08-21**:
i have downloaded common_msgs and inside the sensor_msgs have pasted the 2 msgs that i want, i also have added them in the cmake but when i type rosmake i get that there is no makefile, i added a makefile, everything compiled but i still get the same message.

**Comment by [rem870](https://answers.ros.org/users/5383/rem870/) on 2013-08-21**:
should i delete the sensor_msgs that are on my fuerte/share?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-08-21**:
No, you just need to overlay them correctly, so that roscd sensor_msgs points to that. With define I meant: Make some package on your own. -- As to the wiki, I think that might just be wrong. If you go to the auto-generated code-api the messages aren't in groovy.

**Comment by [rem870](https://answers.ros.org/users/5383/rem870/) on 2013-08-22**:
still not working. i type roscd sensor_msgs it points to my package
but still not working